# Multiple Paginations on Datatable - Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable

I need two paginations for the datatable i.e. a jquery plugin, one at the top of the table and one at the bottom. What I'm doing is following:

```
// get the pagination generated by the plugin
var clonedPag = $("#pagination_bottom").clone();

// add this pagination to the top of table
$("#datatable_wrapper").prepend()
```

The problem is that this newly added pagination won't work.

Can anyone please tell me, what I'm doing wrong or how can I get this to work?

Comment: Here is the documentation : http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1109/duplicating-pagination-bottom-top-of-the-table/p1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have multiple pagination.  Use datatables [sDom](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html) option.

The DataTables web site provides an example, [DataTables DOM positioning - multiple instances](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_multiple_elements.html).

Or, here's a very simple example, http://jsfiddle.net/qdRDw/

```
$('#test').dataTable(
    {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sDom":'fptip'
    });
```

Comment: 15 hours after I found mine.  Glad you selected your own answer as the correct answer pal.